# How would I describe this situation on a CV/to an interviewer?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns

The situation is that I'm a software developer and before Christmas I was asked by a client to help with a site they have.

They had another developer create 90% of a site, then something happened, they had a disagreement I think - they wouldn't say anymore, but I had to step in and complete the project.

How would I describe this situation in a sentence, e.g. for a CV or to an interviewer?

All I can think of is that I "saved" the project but this isn't how I'd want to describe it.

---

I've probably not explained this as well as I need to, the CV/interviewer were the best examples I could think of but I have the actual usage, and format below

> **Title**   (e.g. Dave's Plumbers)
>   **Summary**
>   [Description]

I need a summary consisting **of 5 or less words**

> Due to the previous company not finishing the project, the client was left without a working website. I had to ______ etc.

The best I've come up with is **Project Recovery**, which works but I feel there's a better summary text out there somewhere.

Comment: Do you mean you want to include this incident in your CV as part of your professional accomplishments, achievements or experiences?

Comment: Market yourself as a closer ;)

Comment: @mahmudkoya no, I just want a way to summarize this type of situation, Hank is kind of in the right situation but not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Hank - in the right ball park but not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Rick I was mainly being facetious ;)

Comment: @Rick:So, You were instrumental to show them a way out, when one of your client companies was shut up in a cul-de-sac. You accomplished for them their very much needed software project work which had been half-way abandoned by their software engineer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the phrase the OP used in the second paragraph is fine ....

*You were asked to **step in** to complete the website.*

> **step in**
>   to become involved in a difficult situation or argument in order to help find a solution:
>   [ + to infinitive ] *An outside buyer has stepped in to save the company from going out of business.
>
>   When the leading actress broke her leg, Isobel stepped in and took over.*
>   — [cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/step-in)